# How to connect to a new Pokewalker?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

My brother lost his Pokewalker and got a new one individually to replace it. I looked up about replacements [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pokewalker#Pok.C3.A9mon_retrieval) on Bulbapedia and tried the <kbd>Up</kbd>+<kbd>Select</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> thing.

It gave the Pokemon back, but if you try to connect to the new one, it says it isn't registered. What do I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the Pokewalker connection screen, you must hold `Down`, `X`, and `L` on the DS. This is a necessary step so that you cannot clone Pokemon. After that, you should be able to connect a new Pokewalker.

Comment: Where do you do that?

Answer (score -2):

If you still have HeartGold booklet, follow the instructions on page 35.

Comment: What does it say on page 35?